# El login y la password de la base de dato debe estar registrado en algún sitio?

Tags: java, jquery

Estoy haciendo una BD en java. Tengo una clase conector y trae como atributo un login y una pasword y no se si pude ser la que me de la gana o tiene que estar resgistrado en phpmyadmin o algun sitio. esta es mi clase. Tiene mas metodos y eso pero lo impostante es esto

```
public class ConectorBD {

private String bd = "test";
private String login = "empleado";
private String password = "empleado";
private String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + bd;
private Connection conn = null;

    /**
     * Constructor de DbConnection
     */
    public ConectorBD() {
        try {
            //obtenemos el driver de para mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            //obtenemos la conexión
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            if (conn != null) {
                System.out.println("Conección a base de datos " + bd + ". lista");
            }
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Permite retornar la conexión
     */
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        conn = null;
        System.out.println("La conexion a la  base de datos " + bd + " ha terminado");
    }
```

Comment: La clase lo único que hace es validarte contra la DB para establecer una conexión. Los credenciales que tiene como atributos son el usuario y la contraseña de la DB, por lo que no pueden ser los que te den la gana.

Comment: @phpMyGuel si eso es asi no pude ser lo que quiera no?tiene que ser un usuario y una clave que existan en la BD que esta en phpmyadmin no?

Comment: Exacto. Por defecto suele venir un usuario que es: User: root con pass vacía, pero se pueden crear diferentes usuarios desde tu gestor de DB.